# Extending a continuous function by one point, is the resulting function continuous as well?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let's say I have a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose I extend $f$ to a function $g$ such that  $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ where $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $g(0) = \infty$. Is the resulting function $g$ continuous?

I have an idea to use the pasting lemma somehow, but I cannot seem to convince that the part I'm pasting, $g(0) = \infty$ is actuall continuous. Thanks.

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$ then $g$ is continuous.

Comment: I think you may have a particular situation in mind which you have not fully described. But think about arbitrarily assigning a value for a function at a point (the rest of the continuous function being given) - what chance is there that the resulting function will be continuous? (See Marco's answer for detail of one possibility). This highlights the need to identify the constraints in your problem completely and with precision - but testing like this is just what mathematicians do to identify the gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Then $f$ is also continuous on $\mathbb{R}-{0}$. Clearly, the corresponding function $g$ (refering to your notation) is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply the pasting lemma here because you are pasting the closed set $\{0\}$ with the open set given by its complement. The pasting lemma applies to sets both open or both closed.